# xml/json source surrogate sequence per nesting level

Tags: azure-data-factory, etl, json-deserialization, xml-deserialization

Semi-structure xml/json files are often used to serialize relational data from different levels of entities in a master-detail cascade fashion.
As xml/json files are ordered, unique keys are not necessarily provided to preserve sequencing and hierarchy.

Most ETL's offer a way to de-serialize those entities instances by dispatching them back from an xml/json file into different master-detail cascade of tables, generating a integer on-the-fly surrogate sequence PER LEVEL that can be propagated to both master records (as a unique surrogate key) and detail records (as a referential foreign key to master).

I can't seem to find such a feature in ADF transformations (be it parse, flatten, surrogate, etc.)

- Grouping at master level reaches the goal to uniquely number master records but the link is lost to details
- Flattening the whole xml/json source can be extremely heavy, redundant and entails a lot of re-scan & lookup in order to achieve that objective.

**QUESTION: any smart idea (within ADF) to perform that multiple surrogate sequence numbering per cascading master-detail level in one pass (one scan) over the whole source data set ?**

Thanks

---

@Rakesh : 'should have done that from the very beginning | suppose the following structure (country name could also be nested as regular xml tags) :

```
<geo>
  <country name="USA">
    <city>Miami</city>
    <city>Frisco</city>
  </country>
  <country name="France">
    <city>Paris</city>
    <city>Brest</city>
  </country>
</geo>
```

I would ideally get the following two dataflows to be generated with each an independent sequence keeping track of order and structure :

| country_id | country_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | USA |
| 2 | France |

| country_id | city_id | city_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Miami |
| 1 | 2 | Frisco |
| 2 | 3 | Paris |
| 2 | 4 | Brest |

The following denormalized flow would be OK provided I get both sequences (even within an xml-kept structure)

| country_id | country_name | city_id | city_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | USA | 1 | Miami |
| 1 | USA | 2 | Frisco |
| 2 | France | 3 | Paris |
| 2 | France | 4 | Brest |

That following one is not ok :

| city_id | country_name | city_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | USA | Miami |
| 2 | USA | Frisco |
| 3 | France | Paris |
| 4 | France | Brest |

...because if you think of a very large and deeply nested dataset, it makes a hellish amount of reprocessing and lookups downstream to reconnect master-detail surrogates whereas the previous example only need one pass parsing/pass.

Any idea on how to ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide total xml data? your `country_id` is not there in your xml?

Comment: Hello Rakesh,
That's my total xml data as it was made by hand for the example (but I can add a bunch of French cities if you ever plan to visit ;-) )
No technical surrogate id's provided, that's the point.
But you can easily admit that business PK for country is country name and city name for city (yeah well, there's a Paris in Texas, let's forget about that case)

Comment: I know my staging gymnastics about pulling surrogate from a sequence before pushing to dimensions and fact tables but my point is optimization : rather than transiently indexing and looking up business key for surrogates, I'd like to leverage that data is ordered in the xml file (especially about parenting)